# Java - JList.getSelectedValuesList() not working in jar file

Tags: java, swing

I was writing a program with swing and used a JList for displaying several Objects E. I wanted to be able remove Objects from the list with a button. Within the ActionListener i coded:

```
List<Data> datas = dataList.getSelectedValuesList();
for(Data data : datas)
    deleteData(data);
dataList.setListData(getDatas());
```

This worked perfectly when running it in Eclipse or in the console with 'java -jar xyz.jar'. However, when double clicking on the .jar-file, the remove button wouldn't work at all, nothing was removed from the list and not even an error was produced.

Therefore, I tested the List.getSelectedValues() method:

```
Object[] datas = dataList.getSelectedValues();
for(Object data : datas)
     deleteData((Data)data);
dataList.setListData(getDatas());
```

This method worked perfectly. However, this method is deprecated since JDK 1.7 in favor of getSelectedValuesList(). Can someone explain me the problem? Is it a Java build issue? How can I still use the non-deprecated method?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have multiple java versions installed on your machine?

Comment: Yes I have. How could this be an issue?

Comment: My guess is when you are double clicking the jar it is running with a different version of java, then when you run it from the command line. Try to right click the jar and run with the same version of java that it was compiled with.

Comment: Good guess, didn't think about that, doh! java version 1.7.0 64-Bit in command line, but double click runs java 1.6 32-Bit. Thanks very much for the quick help!

Comment: @Danny  You should upgrade that to an answer, so the OP can mark this as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely have multiple versions of Java installed on you computer. When you are running it from the command line it is running your application with one versions of Java and when you double click another.

Instead of double clicking you should right click and do "Open With..." and select the version of Java that your application was compiled with.

Comment: Thank you for this, had same problem - used same solution. Another quick fix is to use (if appropriate) `getSelectedValue()`, the single-item version of this method, which of course won't give you multiple selected items but it will work across java 6 and 7.